# using java to read data from serial port in Tiny OS

Tags: java, classpath, tinyos

I am going through Tiny OS tutorial lesson number 4 "Mote-PC serial communication and SerialForwarder" and I am stuck on the line where it says
"Once you have installed TestSerial, you need to run the corresponding Java application that communicates with it over the serial port. This is built when you build the TinyOS application. From in the application directory, type

```
$ java TestSerial
```

However when I type this, I face the following error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class TestSerial
```

I tried several things to fix this issue, but none helped.

Solutions that I tried:

1. set CLASSPATH to the directory that I am currently in, which is

export CLASSPATH=.:/home/wsn/tinyos-main/apps/tests/TestSerial

2)set CLASSPATH to the directory where tinyos.jar is located

export CLASSPATH=.:/home/wsn/tinyos-main/support/sdk/java/tinyos.jar

3)run command using `java -cp . TestSerial`

however I keep having the same error

Is there any other better way to fix it?

I am using Virtual Machine with Fedora OS
I am trying to run the program on mib520 platform and I use iris motes

my java version

openjdk version "1.8.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: Is the `TestSerial.class` actually present in your working directory?

Comment: @Michael Jaros no it does not, but tutorial did not mention nothing about it, I guess assuming it should be there by default. I do have TestSerial.java though in there and I tried to run that too using the same commands. Sorry, I am as familiar with java so not sure what exactly is the compilation process

Comment: `TestSerial.java` needs to be compiled before execution: Just call `javac TestSerial.java`. This will create the compiled class file. I guess that from the tutorial's point of view, one of the earlier steps should have done this and did not work as expected.

Comment: bash: javac: command not found....
when I went to java directory which is   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.31-5.b13.fc21.i386/jre/bin/
 I didn't even find javac file

Comment: Java comes in two kinds of distributions, JRE (just for execution) and JDK (for development). Most people need only the JRE, but to be able to compile `.java` files, you need the JDK.

Comment: Ok, all good now. It seemed like I had JDK installed, just did not set up the right folder for the CLASSPATH. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have skipped the step when you had to run the make command.

Navigate to the apps/tests/TestSerial folder and type `make [platform]` (such as make telosb, make iris e.t.c), the makefile that will be run will be the makefile in the TestSerial folder which is defined as follows:

```
COMPONENT=TestSerialAppC
TOSMAKE_PRE_EXE_DEPS += TestSerial.class
TOSMAKE_CLEAN_EXTRA = *.class TestSerialMsg.java

TestSerial.class: $(wildcard *.java) TestSerialMsg.java
    javac -target 1.4 -source 1.4 *.java

TestSerialMsg.java:
    nescc-mig java $(CFLAGS) -java-classname=TestSerialMsg TestSerial.h test_serial_msg -o $@


TINYOS_ROOT_DIR?=../../..
include $(TINYOS_ROOT_DIR)/Makefile.include
```

So the makefile compiles TestSerial.java. After this you can proceed to installing the application and then running the TestSerial application.

So step by step on a iris mote for example you would

1. Navigate to the `apps/tests/TestSerial` Folder
2. Make the application by typing `make iris`
3. Connect your mote and then type `motelist`. This command will list all connected motes. The name of your mote should be listed under the "Device" section. Note this for use in the next two steps.
4. Install your application by typing the command `make iris install.1 bsl, [DEVICE NAME]`. This will make and upload your program to your device.
5. Run the TestSerial application by running `java TestSerial -comm serial@[DEVICE NAME]:iris`

If you use another platform such as telosb then just replace all occurances of iris in the commands above with telosb.

Comment: Hi @KillaKem , the make iris command did not work since til I did not compile TestSerialMsg.java file and added current directory in CLASSPATH, so I guess those steps should be the very first ones. Otherwise everything works now, thanks for your suggestions